# Mathematica Arduino Link

Tags: interoperability, hardware

Has anyone successfully used Arduino Link package to generate code and communicate with the Arduino with Mathematica?

I have tried using it but I get "Failed to upload sketch" when I try to connect the Arduino with Mathematica...

I am using an Arduino Mega

Here is a link to the package on github

https://github.com/keshavsaharia/ArduinoLink

Here is a link to a video that goes into deeper detail of Arduinolink

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3P5JF4whgA

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  In v10.1 and later, there's an "ArduinoLink" in $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Link.  I don't know what this (undocumented) package is exactly, it might simply support [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Arduino.html).  But it is very relevant still because this is what gets loaded when you ``<<ArduinoLink` `` ...  I don't have an Arduino so I never tried these.

Comment: I don't have my UNO handy and I haven't tried with this particular package, but as soon as I get a hold of it I'll take a swing at it. In the meantime, have you tried the built-in package that @Szabolcs pointed out? It's clunky and, in my opinion, much more painful to use than the Arduino IDE but it worked correctly when last I tried it.

Comment: I got it to work with arduino uno and mm 10.0.0. I didn't really use it, I just turned the standby light on and off. I was able to output values also but if I remember correctly, I couldn't get it to read values. I wanted it for data acquisition and so I ended up abandoning the project and decided I would just use labview in the future.

Comment: Szabolcs- I am using Mathematica 10.2. I looked at the link you posted and that was a huge help! I am able to write values to the Arduino pins now! Thank you! However when I try to read pins from the Arduino using  DeviceRead[device,Pin#] it returns " Timed out waiting for response from arduino."

Comment: @David I have used the ArduinoLink that's built in since 10.1 and it works well for me. I can read and write to pins. We will need more information on exactly what you are trying to do in order to pinpoint your problem, I believe.

Comment: Hello David, let me start by saying I am very sorry that there was not better documentation and a more official getting started guide posted. During my time at WR I didn't get a chance to bring the ArduinoLink project to the conclusion it deserved before joining the Wolfram Alpha team. Please let me know by email (keshav@techlabeducation.com) what operating system you're using and I'll try to guide you through the setup as best I can. Once your computer has the correct AVR tools everything should work smoothly.